# How long Anonymous login persists for?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making a chrome extension which uses firebase as its database. The authentication type I'm using is the anonymous one and I'm wondering how long it lasts. I'd want it to last indefinitely so a user always is associated with the same uid. Is there somewhere in the console I can check how long an anonymous sign in lasts?

Answer (score 1):

I emailed the firebase support and got back the response:

`Expiration times are now managed by the Firebase Auth service which can refresh tokens indefinitely. So UID should remain the same.`

So I guess anonymous authentication lasts until `signout` is called, or the user clears his cache/cookies.